# How to give a Method input parameters and print the return value

Tags: java, methods, printing, fibonacci

i need help with my classical exercise - To determine the fibonacci number of a value. I want that the input i give the value "Eingabe" is put into the method into i to determine the fibonacci number. Also i want to print this returned value then. Someone may help?

````
```
      public class fibonacciLinear {
             

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                 
                long Eingabe = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
                
}


public static long Fibonacci (int i){
    if (i == 0) return 0;
    if ( i <= 2) return 1;
    else return Fibonacci(i-1) + Fibonacci(i-2);
}
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Putting a value into a method is called calling a method. The value is an argument that is passed to the method. You can do this, and print it using:

```java
System.out.println("Result: " + Fibonacci(Eingabe));
```

in the `main` method under the `Eingabe` declaration.